# How to get value from list that is in another list which in another list

Tags: java, list, foreach, get, dto

I have a Dto class with variables which one of them is another class. and inside another class there is a variable List with another class.

```
public class GetList {
    private String id;
    private ResultGetList result;
}


public class ResultGetList {
    @JsonProperty("Customer")
    private List<CustomerGetList> customer;
}

public class CustomerGetList {
    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    private String customerId;
    @JsonProperty("bankId")
    private String bankId;
    @JsonProperty("cardholderName")
    private String cardHolderName;
    @JsonProperty("Card")
    private List<CardGetList> Card;
}
```

I open new Dto class for get necessary variables in above classes.

```
public class NewConDto {

    private String id; 
    private String pan;
    private String mfo;
    private String fullName;
}
```

I need set NewConDto values from above Classes.

```
 NewConDto newConDto= new NewConDto();
newConDto.setid(GetList.getResult().getCustomer()....)
```

i don't get after getCustomer because, next value is List.
I need get value from List value which a another Dto class.

Generally speaking, I need something like this:

```
GetList.getResult().getCustomer().foreach(.....getcustomerId());
GetList.getResult().getCustomer().foreach(.....getpan());
GetList.getResult().getCustomer().foreach(.....getmfo());
```

....

How to make for each, to take value from class. Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: So you need to create a `NewConDto` object for each `CustomerGetList` object? `id` comes from `CustomerGetList`? What is the source for other fields: `pan`, `mfo`, `fullName`?

Comment: I should point out that some of your class names are just plain wrong.  For example, `GetList` ... is NOT a list.  And `CustomerGetList` is misleading because an instance seems to represent a single customer not a list of customers.  It strikes me that a lot of you problems are caused by the mis-naming of the classes; e.g. by you thinking that since `GetList` is *called* that ... it must be a list.  (And it isn't!)   In short, correct class names are important for people reading the code, and that includes you.

Comment: I need GetList.getResult().getCustomer().foreach(.....getcustomerId()); GetList.getResult().getCustomer().foreach(.....getpan()); GetList.getResult().getCustomer().foreach(.....getmfo());  GetList.getResult().getCustomer().foreach(.....getfullName());

Comment: You need to make `getResult()` static to invoke it list that (`GetList.getResult()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming**

- You have the correct getters and setters in the class, and you are not showing them here for keeping code short)`humoGetList` -> instance of GetList
- `humoGetList.getResult()` -> results in instance of `ResultGetList`
- `humoGetList.getResult().getCustomer()` -> -> results in instance of `List< CustomerGetList>`

You need to create a new List newConDtoList and fill it with objects. Here are few options:

```java
public class MyProgram{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetList getList = testData();

    // Option 1 : Use For Each Loop

    List<NewConDto> newConDtoList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CustomerGetList customer : testData().getResult().getCustomer()){
      NewConDto newConDto =  convert(customer);
      newConDtoList1.add(newConDto);
    }

    // Option 2: Use for each
    List<NewConDto> newConDtoList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    getList.getResult().getCustomer().forEach(MyProgram::convert);

    // Option 3: Use stream

    List<NewConDto> newConDtoList3 = getList.getResult().getCustomer().stream()
      .map(MyProgram::convert)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());


  }

  private static NewConDto convert(CustomerGetList customer){
    NewConDto newConDto = new NewConDto();
    newConDto.setFullName(customer.getCardHolderName());
    newConDto.setId(customer.getBankId());
    //...
    return newConDto;
  }
  private static GetList testData(){
  ResultGetList resultGetList = new ResultGetList();

    CustomerGetList customerGetList1 = new CustomerGetList();
    customerGetList1.setBankId("bankId1");
    customerGetList1.setCardHolderName("cardHolderName1");
    customerGetList1.setCustomerId("customerId1");
    CardGetList cardList1 = new CardGetList();
    customerGetList1.setCard(Arrays.asList(cardList1));

    CustomerGetList customerGetList2 = new CustomerGetList();
    customerGetList2.setBankId("bankId2");
    customerGetList2.setCardHolderName("cardHolderName2");
    customerGetList2.setCustomerId("customerId2");
    CardGetList cardList2 = new CardGetList();
    customerGetList2.setCard(Arrays.asList(cardList2));

    GetList getList = new GetList();
    getList.setResult(resultGetList);

    return getList;
  }
}
```

Comment: List<NewConDto> newConDtoList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CustomerGetList customer : testData().getResult().getCustomer()){
      NewConDto newConDto =  convert(customer);
      newConDtoList1.add(newConDto);
    }

This code is working., Thanks very much)